# How do I use ARC Welder as an Android emulator

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

Please is there any way to connect ARC Welder to Android studio and use it as an Android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

As InxDev says, you can import your APK into Arc Welder.

Once you've done it though, you don't want to have to go through the whole process every time you create a new APK. What I've found through experimentation is that it's possible after importing it to replace it with a newer version.

Locate the APK under the directory you gave Arc Welder to save files in, then copy the new APK over it. I tried using a symbolic link to the file under Android Studio's directories and that wouldn't start, so evidently it *does* have to be a file. Though on a modern Linux system there's nothing to stop you using inotify to watch for the file changing under Android Studio and have it automatically copied across.

Comment: Is there another way that runs the app in debug mode ?

Answer (score 0):

Export the APK and then upload it to ARC Welder. Is the easier way.